# Install python modules using a graphic interface

Tags: python, batch-file, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a informatic project and I am using python. However, I would like to download modules with a batch file (using : pip install exemple) and I am using a pyqt Window set as a thread with an little animation to simulate the progression of downloads. But I am blocked because my pyqt window needs the installation of pyqt I am doing in the batch file.
Do you have an idea to resolve this problem ? :)
Here is a part of my code:

```
pathDownloads = str(pathFile + '\\Downloads.bat')
username = getpass.getuser()

# ----- Main -----

from Progress import *
def chargement () :

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if not app :
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Progress()
    app.exec()

print('\n::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n'
        ':::::::::::::::::: PROGRESS SCREEN :::::::::::::::::::\n'
        '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n')
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=chargement)
thread1.start()
if thread1.is_alive() == True:
    print('The progress screen as been loaded successfully')
else :
    print('Error')
    pass

time.sleep(2)
print('\n::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n'
        '::::::::::::::: DOWNLOADS OF MODULES :::::::::::::::\n'
        '::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::')
subprocess.call(pathDownloads)
```

Comment: Why do you need a batch file to download something? A batch file just runs one or more commands in sequence, can python not run one or more commands?

Comment: I use it to do : pip install 'example' . But I can not use pip install pyqt5 and use my pyqt window at the same time

Comment: I don't understand: you are already using PyQt, why are you trying to install it again?

Comment: I would like my script must be use as an application for everyone. So I want to do the downloads to run all my script, with a progress screen and then it runs my script